# Remove hard line breaks from text with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have some text with hard line breaks in it like this:

```
This should all be on one line 
since it's one sentence.

This is a new paragraph that
should be separate.
```

I want to remove the single newlines but keep the double newlines so it looks like this:

```
This should all be on one line since it's one sentence.

This is a new paragraph that should be separate.
```

Is there a single regular expression to do this? (or some easy way)

So far this is my only solution which works but feels hackish.

```
txt = txt.gsub(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/,'[[[NEWLINE]]]')
txt = txt.gsub('[[[NEWLINE]]][[[NEWLINE]]]', "\n\n")
txt = txt.gsub('[[[NEWLINE]]]', " ")
```

Comment: What is the source of the text? Often people want to "repurpose" text pulled from a HTML page, and, after extracting the text find it full of breaks. The HTML can provide good clues to the actual layout if it uses `<p>` tags, and smart use of a parser can make quick work of extracting everything in nice clean blocks of paragraphs.

Comment: It's from a web service.  Supposed to be a block of plain text so there is no HTML but it's not very well formed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace all newlines that are not followed by or preceded by a newline:

```
text = <<END
This should all be on one line
since it's one sentence.

This is a new paragraph that
should be separate.
END

p text.gsub /(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/, ' '
#=> "This should all be on one line since it's one sentence.\n\nThis is a new paragraph that should be separate. "
```

Or, for Ruby 1.8 without lookarounds:

```
txt.gsub! /([^\n])\n([^\n])/, '\1 \2'
```

Comment: Clever, thanks!  Took me a minute to understand the regex, but I think I get it.

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to capture the \r\n's but could probably be modified to do so relatively easily.

Comment: Saved my day! Well it was just for the esthetics but that is important too :)

Answer (score 4):

```
text.gsub!(/(\S)[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*(\S)/, '\1 \2')
```

The two `(\S)` groups serve the same purposes as the lookarounds (`(?<!\s)(?<!^)` and`(?!\s)(?!$)`) in @sln's regexes:

- they confirm that the linefeed really is in the middle of a sentence, and
- they ensure that the `[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*` part consumes any other whitespace surrounding the linefeed, making it possible for us to normalize it to a single space.

They also make the regex easier to read, and (perhaps most importantly) they work in pre-1.9 versions of Ruby that don't support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to formatting (turning off word wrap) than you think.
If the output is a result of a formatting operation, then you should go by
those rules to reverse engineer the original.

For instance, the test you have there is

`This should all be on one line`
`since it's one sentence.`

`This is a new paragraph that`
`should be separate.`

If you removed just the single newlines only, it would look like this:

`This should all be on one line since it's one sentence.`
`This is a new paragraph thatshould be separate.`

Also, other formatting such as intentional newlines will be lost, so something like:

```
This is Chapter 1
   Section a 
   Section b
```

Turns into

```
This is Chapter 1   Section a   Section b
```

Finding the newline in question is easy `/(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/`
but, what do you replace it with.

**Edit**: Actually, its not that easy even to find standalone newlines, because visually they sit amongst hidden from view (horizontal) whitespaces.

There are 4 ways to go.

Remove newline, keep the surrounding formatting
`$text =~ s/(?<!\s)([^\S\n]*)\n([^\S\n]*)(?!\s)/$1$2/g;`
Remove newline and formatting, substitute a space
`$text =~ s/(?<!\s)[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*(?!\s)/ /g;`

Same as above but ignore newline at beginning or end of string

`$text =~ s/(?<!\s)(?<!^)[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*(?!$|\s)/ /g;`
`$text =~ s/(?<!\s)(?<!^)([^\S\n]*)\n([^\S\n]*)(?!$|\s)/$1$2/g;`

Example breakdown of regex (this is the minimum required just to isolate a single newline):

```
(?<!\s)      # Not a whitespace behind us (text,number,punct, etc..)
[^\S\n]*     # 0 or more whitespaces, but no newlines
\n           # a newline we want to remove
[^\S\n]*     # 0 or more whitespaces, but no newlines
(?!\s)/      # Not a whitespace in front of us (text,number,punct, etc..)
```

Comment: I think your answer is more complete.  Luckily I don't have to worry about indenting here or anything like that.  This is good detail though for more advanced requirements.

Comment: @Brian - Glad you got it going. Note that this is not advanced, this is the minimum regex. It becomes a nightmare when you do reformatting. People write sentences not programs. How does a program know when wrap a line? It certainly doesen't remove text, it interjects newline.  Either way human or machine, `"...text\n \nParagraph..."` passes this regex `/(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/`, so does `" \n \n \n \n "`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is this:

```
s.gsub /([^\n])\n([^\n])/, '\1 \2'
```

It won't do anything to leading or trailing newlines. If you don't need leading or trailing white space at all, then you will win with this variation:

```
s.gsub(/([^\n])\n([^\n])/, '\1 \2').strip
```

Comment: Clever, thanks!  Took me a minute to understand the regex, but I think I got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ruby -00 -pne 'BEGIN{$\="\n\n"};$_.gsub!(/\n+/,"\0")' file
This should all be on one line since it's one sentence.

This is a new paragraph thatshould be separate.
```